# how to upgrade to ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I am now using ubuntu 10.04 . I want to upgrade to ubuntu 10.10. I have Internet connection with great . what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu’s Update Manager should prompt you that a new distribution upgrade is available. If not, just check if Ubuntu is configured to look for Long Term Support (LTS) releases only. To do this, Click on `System` -> `Admininstration` -> `Update Manager`. Next, click on Settings and change the “Show distribution releases” from “Long Term Support Releases only” to “Normal Releases”

[image]

Hit close, and start Update Manager again, click on check and it should prompt you to update to the newer version

---

From the command line,

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```